# If the html says <div id="two words", how do I write the CSS selector in the style sheet?

Tags: html, css

If it said "oneword", then I could write "#oneword", but what do I write when there is a space in the word?

Comment: Having two ID's is like having two Social Security Numbers.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If it contains spaces, it is not legal HTML.  You shouldn't expect this to work. Here is the relevant section of the [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) specification.

[EDIT] As others have noted, you can get around this by assigning one or more class names to the div and using a class name to do the selection.

Answer (score 33):

You can't have multiple words for the id, but you can for class.

```
<p class="one two">lalala</p>

.one {
    color: black;
}

.two {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Or if you're trying to target an element that has both classes, `.one.two { color: black; font-weight: bold; }`

Answer (score 15):

Write Like this

div[id='two words']{

}

this will recognize the id as combination of both 'two' and 'words'.

Comment: It's not very clean to use an `id` with spaces in it. But this actually works if it is absolutely necessary! Nice

Answer (score 8):

Change it to two-words. Like others said, you cannot use spaces for the id, but you can for the class.

```
#two-words { font-family: arial; }
.center { text-align: center; }
.bold { font-weight: bold; }

<div id="two-words" class="center bold">STUFF HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should not use whitespace in the ID element, as whitespace is generally accepted as a [selector combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#selector-syntax).

Answer (score -1):

If you make websites with IDEs like Artisteer, you can see a working `id="two words"` which becomes a class

```
.two{
}

.words{
}
```

I don't know if this is a good practice, but it works.

Comment: This answer provides no new information to a question asked and answered 4 years ago...

Answer (score -2):

this is work,

```
#two\ words {

}
```

don't use it though, cause id's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.). Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)